# CSS My site layout is messed up

Tags: html, css, layout

Here is [the site](http://bootstrap.netmorerealtor.com), I am using bootstrap grid system. The front page is not so bad, but if click on "Advanced Search" from the left sidebar, the page is all pushed to the left side of the screen, and there are no 30px gutter between the three columns for the main content area. Same problem goes to the search result page.

I've noticed this problem after upgrading to firefox 22.0, I tried to install "NoSquint 2.1.9" and set the global setting back to 80%, that didn't help. Also all other major browsers showing the same issue, lead me believe it's my CSS setting problem, but I looked everywhere and couldn't remember I did any changes.

Need to borrow someone's sharp eyes!

Thanks.

Update:

I apologize for that. Here is a screenshot of the main structure of the "Advanced Search" page where the entire layout is no longer centered in the browser. I couldn't see anything changed in the HTML.

[image: HTML]

Comment: It would help if you track down the relevant code and post it in your question as a [repro](http://sscce.org). That way this question will remain useful to future visitors experiencing similar problems, even when you've fixed your linked site.

Comment: code? we're not psychic (even if we are brilliant)

Comment: Could we ask you to post actual code as opposed to a screenshot? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have different Bootstrap css files on the pages which aren't displaying well.

On the home page you have http://bootstrap.netmorerealtor.com/css/bootstrap.css which I think is the one you want on the search and advanced pages.

On the pages which aren't displaying well, add

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://bootstrap.netmorerealtor.com/css/bootstrap.css">
```

to the head before

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://bootstrap.netmorerealtor.com/css/html.css">
```

and remove

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://bootstrap.netmorerealtor.com/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: You are absolutely correct! although I don't understand how the minified version got messed since it's a copy I downloaded from bootstrap, you helped me solve the problem. Thank you so much!

Comment: Perfect, good luck with your site!